# Checking if string is only letters and spaces

Tags: arrays, c, function, char, c-strings

I wrote this simple code to check if a string is letters and spaces only

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define N 100

int checkString(char str1[]);

void main()
{
    char str1[N];

    scanf("%s", str1);

    printf("%d",checkString(str1));

    getch();
}

int checkString(char str1[])
{
    int i, x=0, p;
    p=strlen(str1);
    for (i = 0; i < p ; i++)
    {
        if ((str1[i] >= 'a' && str1[i] <= 'z') || (str1[i] >= 'A' && str1[i] <= 'Z') || (str1[i] == ' '))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else{ return 0; }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This works fine when I type something like :

```
hello asds //returns 1

hello1010 sasd  // return 0
```

but if I type anything after space it returns `1`, like this :

```
hello 1220  //returns 1

blabla 11sdws // returns 1
```

Can someone please tell me why?

Comment: You know `%s` only reads the first string of chars up to the first whitespace char, right? Thus if you enter `"hello 123"` , then `str` will contain `"hello"`, which conforms to your test of all-letters or spaces. Perhaps `fgets` with a little alteration to trim the trailing newline may be more what you're looking for.

Comment: nope I did not know that , thanks for telling me

Comment: @WhozCraig Detail: `"%s"` first skips leading white space and _then_ reads (and stores) the first string of chars up to the first whitespace `char`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function can be written more simpler and correctly if to use standard C functions `isalpha` and `isblank` declared in header `<ctype.h>` For example

```
#include <ctype.h>

//...

int checkString( const char s[] )
{
    unsigned char c;

    while ( ( c = *s ) && ( isalpha( c ) || isblank( c ) ) ) ++s;

    return *s == '\0'; 
}
```

If you want to check whether a string contains white spaces then instead of function `isblank` you should use function `isspace`.

Take into account that it is not a good idea to use statement `continue` in such simple loops. It is better to rewrite the loop without the `continue` statement.

And instead of function `scanf` it is better to use function `fgets` if you want to enter a sentence The function allows to enter several words as one string until the Enter will be pressed.

For example

```
fgets( str1, sizeof( str1 ), stdin );
```

Take into account that the function includes the new line character. So after entering a string you should remove this character. For example

```
size_t n = strlen( str1 );
if ( n != 0 && str1[n-1] == '\n' ) str1[n-1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot about the numbers

```
int checkString(char str1[]) {
    int i, x=0, p;
    p=strlen(str1);

    for (i = 0; i < p ; i++)
        if ((str1[i] >= 'a' && str1[i] <= 'z') || (str1[i] >= 'A' && str1[i] <= 'Z') || (str1[i] == ' ') || (str1[i] >= '0' && str1[i] <= '9')) {
            continue;
        } else return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

Or better

```
#include <ctype.h>
...

int checkString(char str1[]) {
    int i, x=0, p;
    p=strlen(str1);

    for (i = 0; i < p ; i++)
        if (isalnum(str1[i]) || (str1[i] == ' '))
            continue;
        else return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You missed the point of the question. That numbers are entered is precisely the reason the OP desires function to return 0 for a string such as "hello 123". The problem is the method of reading the string, which *stops* upon the first whitespace.

Comment: @WhozCraig buh... Yes, I have definitely missed it then.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are taking input with scanf(%s,&str). In this way of input only characters before space \n or other whitespace characters are stored. So your when you enter space the input is stored only upto space.

eg, you input helloo 1234
  Your str stores only helloo and 1234 remains in buffer. Try using getchar().

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define N 100

int checkString(char str1[]);

void main() 
 {
  char str1[N];
  int i=0;
  while(1)
  {
   str1[i++]=getchar();
   if(str1[i-1]=='\n') break;
   }
  printf("%d",checkString(str1));
  getch();
 } 

int checkString(char str1[])
 {
  int i, x=0, p;
  p=strlen(str1);
  for (i = 0; i < p ; i++)
    {
    if ((str1[i] >= 'a' && str1[i] <= 'z') || (str1[i] >= 'A' && str1[i] <= 'Z') || (str1[i] == ' '))
    {
        continue;
    }
    else{ return 0; }
  }
  return 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your input String 
`scanf()` which will take your input up to space only as it is `whitespace`

So when you input as **hello 1234** actual input it is checking is **hello** . Check this by printing what you are taking input (that is print `str1`). Then you will come to know mistake in this code.

You can use `gets` or `fgets` to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `scanf("%s",str1);`,you input `hello 112`,what str1 gets is `hello`.So you can use `fgets(str1,N,stdin);` to get the string.I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

if you print back the string you just scanf()ed you will notice that it only gets the first portion of all inputs. i.e. anything after the white space including the white space is ignored. 
you could use getch() (windows) or getchar() (linux) to get every char input and terminate when you have a "\n" (newline)

source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N 100

int checkString(char str1[]);

void main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int c;
    char str1[N];

    memset(str1, 0, sizeof(str1));

    do {
        c = getchar();
        str1[i++] = c;
    } while ((c != '\n') && (i < (N - 1))); // (i < N - 1) reserves one place for null char

    // last char is '\n' - remove it.
    str1[i-1] = 0;

    printf("Result: %s\n", checkString(str1) ? "letters and/or spaces only" : "other characters other than spaces and/or letters present");
}

// expects a null terminated string
int checkString(char str1[])
{
    char* p = str1;

    while (*p) {

        if (!isalpha(*p) && !isspace(*p)) {
            return 0;
        }
        p++;
    }

    return 1;
}
```